# Node - Recognice if a file was removed or added

Tags: node.js

Is there a smart performant way to watch a **folder and its subfolders** for files being **added or removed** in node js?

Comment: You should use version control like Mercurial or Git and then simply run a git status or hg status command

Comment: DVCS would be a poor substitute for a filesystem watcher.  What if a file changed every 5 seconds?  DVCS have no facility track that unless you are polling every second and committing every change.  That would result in a huge DAG for any non-trivial application.

Comment: @jantimon, what platform do you need this to work on?  It looks like the watching API in node can be platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the node fs API directly:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

But that doesn't do recursive watches (on all platforms).  You could write an extension using that API, or use something existing like:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch

```
var watch = require('node-watch');

watch('somedir_or_somefile', function(filename) {
  console.log(filename, ' changed.');
});
```